# How to get the current week from date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm actually trying to reproduce this kind of calendar:
[image]

What I want is simple, I'm trying to get for the second columns a dynamic display for the days. I'm finding a magic function that will return the 7 next day from a specific day. Or if exists an approach to solve this problem ?

In the example we could have this format: `["Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon"]` because the current day is Tuesday.

But if the current day is Wednesday, I would like to get this format: `["Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue"]`

Actually I'm using `l(Date.today, format: '%a').titleize` to get the current day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
today = Date.today
(today..(today + 7)).map { |d| l(d, format: '%a').titleize }
```

So

```
def short_days_of_week_from_date(date)
  (date..(date + 7)).map { |d| l(d, format: '%a').titleize }
end
```